# iTunes Search API - HTTPS artworkUrl?

Tags: api, itunes

When I run a query against the iTunes Search API over SSL, most of the URL's returned are provided via HTTPS:

https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=rihanna

However, the artworkUrl results are served over HTTP and updating them manually throws an error since the SSL certificate doesn't match on the domain they're using.

Is there a way to grab these images over HTTPS instead of HTTP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iTunes does not support the album art or song previews over HTTPS (yet).

The change over of the tools and links to HTTPS was recent (only four months ago):
http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/blog/secure-links-to-itunes---content-and-tools.html

Comment: It's been several years since this answer was accepted -- has anything changed?

Comment: It doesn't look like it. I've come here trying to find https link to use within an app with ATP.

Answer (score 10):

You have to replace the sub domain:

```
http://is<n> with https://is<n>-ssl
```

Example:

http://is5.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music117/v4/dd/48/4a/dd484afb-2313-0a1a-ccf1-ff28a02ae2ca/source/100x100bb.jpg

to

https://is5-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music117/v4/dd/48/4a/dd484afb-2313-0a1a-ccf1-ff28a02ae2ca/source/100x100bb.jpg

Answer (score 0):

New to SO and Swift - stumbled over this problem until finding this Q, and the answers above.  The following worked for me:

```
func withHTTPS() -> URL? {
  var components = URLComponents(url: self, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true)
  components?.scheme = "https"
  let host = (components?.host)!
  components?.host = host.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: "-ssl.", options: .caseInsensitive, range: host.range(of: "."))
  return components?.url
}
```

called using:

```
guard let url = item.artworkURL.withHTTPS() else { return }
```